# How Can I use saveAsTextFile on my pyspark output that is in the form of a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to count the frequency of bigrams and list the top 5 most frequent ones. I'm able to print the output but get an "attribute error" when I try to use saveAsTextFile to save my results in .out file format.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from operator import add
from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: bigram <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext()
    lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1], 1)
    sentences = lines.glom() \
                  .map(lambda x: " ".join(x).replace(","," ").replace(".", " ").replace("{"," ").replace("}"," ").lower()) \
                  .flatMap(lambda x: x.split("."))
    #print(sentences)
    #Your code goes here
    bigram_pair = sentences.map(lambda x: x.split()) \
        .flatMap(lambda x: [((x[i],x[i+1]),1) for i in range (0, len(x)-1)])
    frequency = bigram_pair.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y) \
        .map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])) \
        .sortByKey(False) \
        .take(100)


    print (frequency)
    frequency.saveAsTextFile("result.out")


    sc.stop()
```

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve? Because it is somehow not clear from your question